# How to Implement the JSONP formatter in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, jsonp, servicestack

Currently in my web API below mentioned class is implemented

```
    public class ServiceStackTextFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public ServiceStackTextFormatter()
        {
            JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: true, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));


        }
}
```

I just want to how can I implement the JSNOP in ServiceStack, I know we can implement this using Newtnsoft json. I have tried using below mentioned code and it's working fine.

```
 public class FormatterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterFormatters
                (MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters)
    {
        var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };
        formatters.Insert(0, jsonFormatter);
        var jsonpFormatter =
                new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(formatters.JsonFormatter);
        formatters.Insert(1, jsonpFormatter);
    }
}
```

so I just want to know how can I achive using ServiceStack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack already has JSONP support built-in for all Services by adding `?callback=cb` to the QueryString, e.g: http://techstacks.io/overview?callback=cb

Which will wrap the JSON response in the specified JS callback, e.g:

```
cb({...})
```